# How to implement google play services in nativescript plugin seed?

Tags: android, typescript, plugins, google-api, nativescript

I'm writing a plugin for nativescript using the recommended nativescript-plugin-seed: https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-plugin-seed.
For my plugin i need to use the Google Location service but i can't access the service.

I implemented the dependencies in my include.gradle in the android folder:

```js
dependencies {
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0"
}
```

Then i try to use the service in myApp.android.ts like this:

```js
let client = com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
```

It always tells me the property 'gms' does not exist on 'typeof android' and i don't know what i am missing.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to just fetch the location then you may add [nativescript-geolocation](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-geolocation) plugin as a dependency in your plugin then use the plugin APIs to fetch location.

If you like some customisation you may go head and implement your own version within your plugin keeping [android implementation](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-geolocation/blob/master/src/geolocation.android.ts) as an example.

If you want are planning to make your plugin available for public usage, try not to stick to a specific version in gradle file.

```
dependencies {
    def googlePlayServicesVersion = project.hasProperty('googlePlayServicesVersion') ? project.googlePlayServicesVersion : "11.4.0"
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:$googlePlayServicesVersion"
}
```

Comment: I want to create a plugin for geofences so i want to use the Google Geofence Service for that. I'll look into the android implementation for some references.